# How can I stream large arrays in gRPC (c#) fast without extreme memory use?

Tags: c#, memory-management, streaming, protocol-buffers, grpc

I want to use gRPC to stream large arrays of data (multiple GB). To do this I send the array in small packages of a few MB each. The problem Im running into is that both server and client side allocates a large number of buffers and the GC is very lazy at cleaning these up. This means that when sending a 2 GB array both client and server side may hold the entire array in memory just as temporary non-GCed buffers.

On the server side, the streaming service looks like the code below. The issue seems to be that the message (DataArrayPart - autogenerated using protobuffers) contains a field Data which is a repeated field of floats. When writing to this field there is no way to directly copy into the internal array inside Data except using the methods Clear and Add. This means that the entire buffer must be cleared and reallocated for each message and the GC is all but eager to clean up these buffers.

I can of course write element by element as in the out commented section below. But this slows thing down quite a bit, about 30%. There are of course a few hacks possible too, such as using reflection to access the underlying array in Data (it is a private member) or force the GC to run. But there must be a better way, or?

```
    public override async Task StreamRead(StreamRequest request, IServerStreamWriter<global::DataArrayPart> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        // Note that the variable data contains the data to be sent. 

        int max_size = 1000_000;
        int n = data.Length;

        float[] arr = new float[max_size];
        var da = new DataArrayPart();
        da.TotalSize = n;

        for (int i = 0; i < n - max_size; i += max_size)
        {
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 4 * i, arr, 0, 4 * max_size);

            // Copy into the buffer fast
            da.Data.Clear();
            da.Data.Add(arr);

            // Slow copy - but prevents extensive memory use.
            //for (int k = 0; k < arr.Length; k++)
            //    da.Data[k] = arr[k];

            await responseStream.WriteAsync(da);
        }

        // Send the last n - max_size elements. Not implemented.
    }
```

Comment: Not really any better solution, unless you want to rewrite protobuf. Are you sure that for loop is slow?

Comment: Are you open to 3rd party tools? I'm pretty confident that this could be implemented using protobuf-net.Grpc using a custom marshaller, for example, or protobuf-net v3 using a custom serializer - using the array pool for leased buffers. But if you're limited to *just* the Google/Microsoft libs, then it really isn't worth me trying to write an example. This would also mean a change from using .proto to define the contract, to using code-first - at least just for that one service.

Comment: @Charlieface Using the for-loop results in 220MB/s while the copy method manages 320MB/s.

Comment: @Marc Gravel: Im can definately be open for other solutions. It doesnt have to be gRPC even, but its the best I've seen so far. Im looking for something that can communicate vary fast from c# to other programs such as scripts running in Python or Matlab or applications written in C++. So I need something that can communicate independtly of the language.

Comment: How was `DataArrayPart` generated, I'm not aware of protobuf doing autogeneration?

Comment: @Charlieface protobuf / gRPC normally generates code from .proto schemas, using the protoc tool; other ways of working it are available, though

Comment: @AndersG that is possible - it can be made compatible with your existing API, even; I don't have time to put an example together right now - is there a timescale in mind here? for example, can you wait a few days?

Comment: @Marc Gravel: I can absolutely wait a few days or a week. Thanks a lot :)